# Chrome devtool highlight and scroll to

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling, web-development

Generally when I open elements tab in dev tools, I scroll over elements to see them being highlighted in the page. But most of the times I will need to scroll the page as the selected element is not visible in browser.

Is there a setting such that when I hover over an element source the page scrolls to appropriate position so that it is highlighted and visible in visible portion of the page automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the element, then click the "Scroll into view" item.